# Show DB content in template sorted by date

Tags: python, django

I'm currently showing the content in the template ordered by sequence_number

#models:

```
class FlowPhase(models.Model):
    sequence_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

#viewset

```
# Function to define sort criteria
def take_seq_number(elem):
    return elem['flow_phase']['sequence_number']

def phase_details(request, batch_pk):
    ph_details_url = API_HOST + "/api/phase_details_full/?batch=" + str(batch_pk)
    answer = requests.get(ph_details_url).json()


    ph_details = answer['results']  


    ph_details.sort(key=take_seq_number)  # <------ sorting by sequence number

    rendered_page = render(request, 'batches_phases/consumer/phase_details.html', {'ph_details': ph_details})
    return rendered_page
```

So, I want to show the content of ph_details in the template ordered by **updated_at** and not by **sequence_number** anymore.

Any suggestions on how to do this in python? In this case, I believe that the changes would only be in

```
ph_details.sort(key=take_seq_number)
```

and

```
def take_seq_number(elem):
     return elem['flow_phase']['sequence_number']
```

**My difficulty is that since sequence_number is integer, it's easier to sort. But how to do this with dates?**

Comment: Why do you make a request to your API instead of querying the database directly? Is there a reason?

Comment: there is an api for this application and all requests go through the api

Comment: Ok, but can't you just query your models directly? Seems like a waste if there is no special reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a new sort method and pass that as the `key` param of the `sort()` function

something like:

```
def sort_phase_updated_at(elem):
    return elem['flow_phase']['updated_at']

ph_details.sort(key=sort_phase_updated_at)
```

Comment: this is giving me a keyerror

Comment: You will have to provide the payload that is returned so that we can figure out the dict access and potentially account for values not being there. Either way, you should be able to figure it out using the docs for `.sort()` [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html). As mentioned in some comments, another option is to sort in the API call if the API allows ordering params.